# AtTask API - return the complete custom forms which can be added to an object

Tags: forms, field, restful-url, attask

I would like to retrieve a list of all custom forms that can be added to issues of a certain project.

Right now I can retrieve the categoryID of a custom form IF there's already an issue made with that custom form added to it and see the filled in fields if any.

```
 https://DOMAIN.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/issue/search?method=GET&projectID=PROJECT_ID&fields=parameterValues,categoryID
```

Makes sense, as in that query I am just listing all issues and requesting extra fields for the categoryID and parameterValues.

But I want to request the prototype form? I guess? The full, complete form for a given category ID. And a full list of all categoryIDs that can be added to an issue or other object.

Essentially, I want to recreate the drop down list you see when you try to add a custom form to an issue on the AtTask website itself.

It shows the list of forms you can choose from, and then creates the html. So somewhere there has to be a list of all custom forms, in their entirety, and a value that determines where they can be added. Is it possible to get that information using the API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines what custom forms can be selected is based on group so if you want to find all custom forms someone can select for issues you can run the following call.

GET api/v4.0/CTGY/search?catObjCode=OPTASK&otherGroupIDs={GroupID}&otherGroupIDs_Mod=in